# After I've inputed the number of questions and the difficulty it stops running

Tags: java

After I've inputted the number of questions and the question difficulty the code stops running like it's finished. It doesn't display any errors it just stops. This is a code I'm writing for an introductory Java programming class and its meant to keep displaying operations for the user to solve, then say whether they were right or wrong and give them a grade.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class MathPractice {
public static int getNumberOfQuestions(int questions) {
    while (questions >= 1 || questions < 1) {
    if (questions >= 1) {
        questions = questions;
    } else {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("The number of questions must be 1 or more. ");
        System.out.print("How many questions do you want? ");
        questions = keyboard.nextInt();
    }}
    return questions;
}

public static int getQuestionDifficulty(int difficulty) {
    while (difficulty <= 1 || difficulty >= 2) {
    if (difficulty < 1 || difficulty > 2) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Valid levels are 1 or 2. Please re-enter. ");
        System.out.print("What difficulty level do you want (1=low or 2=high)? ");
        difficulty = keyboard.nextInt();
    } else {
        difficulty = difficulty;
    }}
    return difficulty;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char keepGoing = 'y';
    char stop = 'n';
    char answer = keepGoing;
    for(int counter = 0; counter >= 0; counter++) {
        if (answer == stop) {
            System.out.print("Session Statistics");
    } else if (answer == keepGoing) {
        System.out.print("How many questions do you want? ");
        int questions = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What difficulty level do you want (1=low or 2=high)? ");
        int difficulty = keyboard.nextInt();
        questions = getNumberOfQuestions(questions);
        difficulty = getQuestionDifficulty(difficulty);
    for (int i = 0; i < questions; i++) {
    if (difficulty == 1) {
        Random random = new Random();
    String operatorSwitch = null;
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = random.nextInt(10);
    int num3 = random.nextInt(10);
    int num4 = random.nextInt(9) +1;

    int operator = random.nextInt(4);

    switch (operator){

        case 0: operatorSwitch = "+";
            num1 = (num2 + num3);
            break;
        case 1: operatorSwitch = "-";
            num1 = (num2 - num3);
            break;
        case 2: operatorSwitch = "*";
            num1 = (num2 * num3);
            break;
        case 3: operatorSwitch = "/";
            num3 = num4;
            num1 = (num2 / num3);
            break;
    }    
        System.out.print("Question #" + i + ": What is " + num2 + operatorSwitch + num3 + "? ");
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(input != num1) {
            System.out.print("Wrong... The answer is " + num1);
        counter = counter - 1;
        } else if(input == num1) {
            System.out.print("Correct!");
        }
      System.out.printf("You answered " + counter + "out of " + questions + "correctly (%.2f%%)", (counter / questions)); 
      System.out.print("Would you like another set of questions? (y/n) ");
      answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    } else if (difficulty == 2) {
        Random random = new Random();
        String operatorSwitch = null;
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = random.nextInt(19) - 9;
        int num3 = random.nextInt(19) - 9;
        int num4 = random.nextInt(9) + 1;

        int operator = random.nextInt(5);

        switch (operator){

            case 0: operatorSwitch = "+";
                num1 = (num2 + num3);
                break;
            case 1: operatorSwitch = "-";
                num1 = (num2 - num3);
                break;
            case 2: operatorSwitch = "*";
                num1 = (num2 * num3);
                break;
            case 3: operatorSwitch = "/";
                num3 = num4;
                num1 = (num2 / num3);
                break;
            case 4: operatorSwitch = "%";
                num1 = (num2 % num3);
        }    
            System.out.print("Question #" + i + ": What is " + num2 + operatorSwitch + num3 + "? ");
            int input = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(input != num1) {
                System.out.println("Wrong... The answer is " + num1);
            counter = counter - 1;
            } else if(input == num1) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            }
          System.out.printf("You answered " + counter + "out of " + questions + "correctly (%.2f%%)", (counter / questions)); 
          System.out.print("Would you like another set of questions? (y/n) ");
          answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    }}
}
}
    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then.

Comment: `getNumberOfQuestions()` is an endless loop

Comment: because `difficulty <= 1 || difficulty >= 2` inside getQuestionDifficulty is always true, so the while cicle will run forever

Comment: `getQuestionDifficulty` is an endless loop as well

Answer (score 0):

```
while (questions >= 1 || questions < 1) {
if (questions >= 1) {
    questions = questions;
else [...]
```

This part will probably loop infinitely, once you enter any number >0.

Actually, this is also (and especially) true for your loop in `getQuestionDifficulty()`

Comment: So how would I fix those two methods to keep them from looping infinitely